# Rollback on error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure in a SQL Server 2008 database. This stored procedure is responsible for updating records in tables across about a dozen tables. The basic idea is show here:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table2 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table3 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table4 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table5 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table6 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table7 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table8 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table9 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table10 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table11 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table12 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
```

There is a possibility where a foreign key constraint is violated. Or some other potential errors. Because of this, I wanted to wrap all of these in some sort of transactional unit. In the event that some error occurred, I just wanted to basically restore the records to their values before this block was executed. I thought a transaction was designed to do this. However, I can't seem to find an example of what I'm trying ot do.

Can someone provide an example of how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or do I misunderstand the purpose of a transaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Example C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) in the `TRY...CATCH` topic in BOL.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set Xact_Abort On;
GO
Begin Transaction;

UPDATE Table1 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table2 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table3 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table4 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table5 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table6 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table7 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table8 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table9 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table10 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table11 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
UPDATE Table12 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue

Commit Transaction;
```

`Set Xact_Abort On` ensures that if any statement failes, the entire transaction rollsback.

[SET XACT_ABORT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think Thomas' answer will do what you need the easiest, so I've voted for that one. But just for completeness sake, here's a basics example of how rollback/commmit/transaction logic generally works in stored procedures:

Basically, you need to wrap your SQL in a transaction, and then [roll back](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) if there's an error after any statement, or commit at the end if there wasn't. Something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE Table1 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table2 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table3 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table4 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table5 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table6 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table7 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table8 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table9 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table10 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table11 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

UPDATE Table12 SET [Field1]=@newValue WHERE [Field1]=@originalValue;
SELECT @errorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@errorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

COMMIT TRANSACTION

PROBLEM:
IF (@errorCode <> 0) BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Error in stored procedure.', 16, 1)
RETURN @errorCode
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: @Martin - Are things different in 2008? I'm using 2005 here so I might not be totally up to date.

Comment: Yes (and in 2005 as well for that matter!). You can just use `TRY...CATCH` rather than needing to laboriously check the value of `@@ERROR` after every statement.

Comment: @Martin - Thanks! Didn't know that. It's been a while since I wrote a stored procedure. I cobbled this example together from memory and information found in a couple quick Google searches. I'll read up on current practice.